# Xcode 11.6 crushes when I open react native project file

Tags: xcode, react-native, expo

I have recently ejected my project from expo to bare react native and I wanted to build my project with Xcode but every time I try to open project files (.xcodeproj and .xcworkspace) inside ios directory Xcode crushes. has anyone come across the same issue or are there any possible solutions to this as I can not also see any errors other than app crush to diagnose the issue.

FYI here are my react-native info

```
System:
    OS: macOS 10.15.6
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8259U CPU @ 2.30GHz
    Memory: 98.73 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 5.7.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.6.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: Not Found
    npm: 6.14.6 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.9.1 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 13.6, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.4, watchOS 6.2
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 29
      Build Tools: 29.0.2
      Android NDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 4.0 AI-193.6911.18.40.6626763
    Xcode: 11.6/11E708 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 1.8.0_265 - /usr/bin/javac
    Python: 3.7.6 - /Users/amiinamo/.pyenv/shims/python
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: ~16.11.0 => 16.11.0 
    react-native: ~0.62.2 => 0.62.2 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

Comment: Ciao, which version of Xcode you are using?

Comment: Ciao, I have updated my question to reflect the Xcode version which is 11.6.